# traversing daily dump directories

Tags: python, awk, directory

I have 6 months of data to go through, looking like this

```
0101
0102
.
.
0131
0201
0202
.
.
all the way to
0630
```

I want  to fo through each directory, and execute an awk file on the contents, or do it in a weekly manner (each 7 directories will make one week of data

is there an easy way to do this in awk or python?

many thanks

Comment: In python, have a look at `os.walk` and `subprocess.call`.  Between those two and your awk script, you should be able to do it pretty easily.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `find` to walk your tree and `xargs` to apply your awk script:

```
find . -type f | xargs awk -f awkfile
```

EDIT: awk syntax corrected thanks to input from @nya. I Am Not An AWK Expert.

Comment: +1; was going to post something similar.  I'd use Python if I actually had Python things to do in each directory, but just running `awk`?  The shell is more likely the right tool for the job.

Comment: BTW, you need `-f` option to run an awkfile, otherwise awk will interpret its argument as program-text

Answer (score 0):

Why not use plain `bash`? You can try this:
`find . -type f -exec awk -f 'your_awk_script.awk' {} \;`

`find` traverses through directory tree, and `-exec` option makes it execute the given comand(in this case `awk -f your_awk_script.awk`) on each file(`{}` is the default placeholder for argument).

To run this tiny script every seven days, look into `cron`.